# pass variable to addEventListener in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

This is my test function

```
 function test(MyCard){
alert("clickCard");
//alert MyCard.GetNo();
}
```

And this is how I call it

```
    (function(MyCard) {
        DivCarte.addEventListener("click", function(e) { test(MyCard); });
    })(MyCard);
```

First alert works fine but if I uncomment the second alert, my page dont show.

This is the card class as requested

```
function Card(No,Kind){  
var No;  
var Kind;   

this.GetNo = function(){  
    //return this.No;  
    return 'test';
}  

this.GetKind = function(){  
    return this.Kind;  
}  

 this.No = No;  
  this.Kind = Kind; 
}
```

Comment: I suspect the error is in the function referenced in the commented line. Please provide the code for that one.

Comment: Just to verify: is `alert MyCard.GetNo()` pseudocode? That's definitely not legit syntax.

Comment: Just edited to add the card class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert is a function, so you should do:

```
 alert( MyCard.GetNo() );
```

Comment: @Pink: That's too long to work on a syntax error when you could just run your code through a validator like http://jshint.com/